# Subset data within function based on value in any column

Tags: r

Let's say I want to write a function like:

```
Fn <- function(df, to_remove = NULL) {
  df <- df[!df %in% to_remove,]
}
```

The purpose is to remove all values in a row (not row numbers/indices/names) where one of the values is equal to value(s) specified in to_remove.

Any idea why this doesn't work without specifying a column?

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("a", "a", "a"), b = c("a", "b", "a"))

  a b
1 a a
2 a b
3 a a
```

Expected output:

```
  a b
1 a a
3 a a
```

I'm looking for a `base R` or `data.table` solution.

Comment: Are you trying to remove a row if the `to_remove` argument appears in any column? You might check out the `filter_*` variants in `dplyr`, e.g (`filter_all`).

Comment: Should work, but would like to avoid writing functions with dplyr for the moment (data.table approach would be fine though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove rows, you need to provide row indices with negative sign or vector (typically of same length as `nrow(df)`) with `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Your code `!df %in% to_remove` does not do that. Try this -

```
Fn <- function(df, to_remove = NULL) {
  df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% to_remove)), ]
}

Fn(df, "b")
  a b
1 a a
3 a a

Fn(df, c("a", "b"))
[1] a b
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Fn(df, "d")
  a b
1 a a
2 a b
3 a a
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this only removes the rows with indices in to_remove. What I'm interested in is to remove the values within the columns. For instance, in above case I may be interested in removing all rows in the dataset where one of the rows is equal to 0.2.

Comment: @arg0naut, I think you are contradicting yourself: *Removing values within the columns* **!=** *removing all rows in the dataset where one of the rows is equal to 0.2*

Comment: @Roman not sure where the contradiction lies as I'm not referring to row names or row indices or row numbers. Perhaps I should have specified row values; but I've added an example now.

Comment: @arg0naut...I misunderstood your question...anyways have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Shree, this seems to be working. However, will wait a bit before accepting since I find `any` to be quite slow and I hesitate to use functions like that.

Comment: I think `any` should be one of the fastest since it terminates the moment it encounters the first `TRUE`. `all` can be slow since it has to check all values. Anyways you can also use `sum(x %in% to_remove) > 0` instead of `any`.

Comment: I microbenchmarked all of the solutions here, and Roman's loop scores 1157ms, `sum` 39ms and `any` 36ms. So still `any` seems to be winning. Let's see if someone else comes up with something, otherwise I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple loop?

```
rowrem <- function(x, val) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
        for(j in 1:ncol(x)){
            if(paste(x[i,j]) == val)(
                x <- x[-i,]                
            )
        }
    }
    print(x)
}
```

Result

```
> rowrem(df1, "b")
  a b
1 a a
3 a a
```

**Explanation**: What you want to do is check every single value of every single cell and refer that back to the row number. With base R your choices are a bit limited in that regard. A sensible (i.e., maintainable) solution would probably be something like above, but I'm sure someone will come up with a `lapply` or subsetting solution as well.

#### Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c("a", "a", "a"), b = c("a", "b", "a"))
```

Comment: While this works, I would like to avoid using loops inside functions; will rather stick to `apply` family, but thanks anyway!